# Cartier divisor corresponds to Weil divisor on a curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $E= \{y^{2}z = x^{3} - xz^{2}\}\subset \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $P = [0:0:1]$ be a point and let $D$ be a Weil divisor correspons to the one point, i.e. $D = P$. 
How to find a corresponding Cartier divisor on $E$? 
Also, I want to show that two line bundles $\mathscr{O}(2D), \mathscr{O}(3D)$ are globally generated.

What I tried is to cover $E$ with three affine open sets $U_{0}, U_{1}, U_{2}$ and find appropriate rational functions $f_{0}, f_{1}, f_{2}$ so that the collection $\{(U_{i}, f_{i})\}$ gives the corresponding Cartier divisor for $D$. Here $U_{i}$s are standard cover of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$. 
However, if we put $f_{0} = f_{1} = 1$, then I can't find suitable $f_{2}$ which only has a simple zero at $P$, so I think I have to try other $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$. But I stucked.

Comment: $[x:y:z] \mapsto \frac{y}{x}$ has $2$ simple poles at $ [0:0:1],[0:1:0]$ and $2$ simple zeros at $[1:0:1],[-1:0:1]$ so won't  the Cartier divisor scheaf of $[0:0:1]$ will be $[x:y:z] \mapsto \frac{x}{y}\mathcal{O}(U_1)^\times$ on $U_1= \{ [x:y:1] \in E, y \ne \pm 1\}$ and $[x:y:z] \mapsto \mathcal{O}(U_2)^\times$ on $U_2=\{ [x:y:z]\in E, y \ne 0\}$. Where $\mathcal{O}(U_1)$ is the subring of $k(E)$ with no poles on $U_1$ and $k(E) $ is the field of rational functions $E \to k$ in $ax,ay,az$ and not depending on $a$